# solr partial search for alphanumeric field not working

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I am using solr 4.4.0. I want to enable partial search on one of the fileds i.e. search key `abc` would return all docs having the filed value as `abc123`,`abc125` etc. I am trying to do this via `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`.

My schema.xml:

```
<fields>
  <field name="variant_sku" type="string" indexed="false" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="false" />
  <field name="parsku" type="text_sku" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
</fields>

<copyField source="variant_sku" dest="parsku"/>
<copyField source="parsku" dest="allText"/>



<fieldType name="text_sku" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type = "index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type = "query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

my solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <str name="wt">json</str>
   <str name="indent">true</str>
   <str name="df">allText</str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I reloaded and did a full data import after making the schema changes. But the partial search does not appear. No results are returned for the query `abc`

**EDIT:** Changed the field_type as @D_K suggested to:

```
<fieldType name="text_sku" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type = "index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateAll="1" splitOnNumerics="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type = "query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateAll="1" splitOnNumerics="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Also tried:

```
<fieldType name="text_sku" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type = "index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type = "query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateAll="1" splitOnNumerics="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

But still facing the same issue.

**EDIT2**: tried the solution [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/NGram-query-failing-td504403.html)

```
<fieldType name="text_sku1" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true"> 
  <analyzer> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" /> 
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" /> 
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="10" minGramSize="2" /> 
  </analyzer> 
  <analyzer type="query"> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" /> 
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" /> 
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="10" minGramSize="2" /> 
  </analyzer> 
</fieldType>
```

not working either!!

Comment: solr analysis page gives a really good view into indexing and querying. Can you check in there, that the indexing of abc and searching of it is as expected? Does your data contain abc?

Comment: @D_K : I am getting the following in analysis page `text
raw_bytes
start
end
type
position
psjai
[70 73 6a 61 69]
0
5
<ALPHANUM>
1
SF
text
raw_bytes
type
position
start
end
psjai
[70 73 6a 61 69]
<ALPHANUM>
1
0
5
LCF
text
raw_bytes
position
start
end
type
psjai
[70 73 6a 61 69]
1
0
5
<ALPHANUM>
`

Comment: @D_K I used abc only as an example. My query is psjai

Comment: this looks like a query side analysis output. What does the indexing side analysis look like for the real data that should match psjai? Perhaps, you could add a screenshot?

Comment: @D_K : Index side analysis is apeears ok: psjai broken to `ps`, `psj`, `psja` and `psjai`

Comment: ps
[70 73]
0
5
1
1
word
psj
[70 73 6a]
0
5
1
1
word
psja
[70 73 6a 61]
0
5
1
1
word
psjai
[70 73 6a 61 69]
0
5
1
1
word

Comment: what is the query you are shooting?

Comment: @D_K my query is `psjai`. My expected result is all the products whose sku starts with `psjai` E.g psjai20021,psjai20022,psjai20023 etc

Comment: right. But then the problem is not in the edge n-gram creation, but in the tokenization process: the numbers will get tokenized out, i.e. they will form their own tokens in the index. Consider using http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory with catenateAll=1 instead of StandardFilterFactory

Comment: @D_K : Still the same. :(

Comment: how does your schema look like now? Can post an update to the question?

Comment: thanks. You should also have splitOnNumerics=1 on the WDFF at least

Comment: oh, and I would set preserveOriginal=1 as well just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the WordDelimiterFilterFactory with splitOnNumerics=1 option should work just fine in your case. You don't need NGram filter because that would be an over-kill for your index.

So this should be sufficient:

```
<fieldType name="text_sku" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateAll="1" splitOnNumerics="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Few things to watch for:

- Re-index your documents if you change the schema. Basically when you change any of the filters used in index time.
- Check the fields you are searching against. I can see you are setting the df to allText, while you are changing type of parsku field. So I hope this is not just a mistake, so make sure you search against parsku field.

if you can also post your search query url, that would be helpful.

Comment: Should this be same for analyzer type `index` and `query` both?

Comment: I would like to search on multiple fields. I am copying all the required fileds into `allText`.

Comment: Just make sure that allText has the analyzer that you need, because copyField doesn't copy the analyzers with it, it just copy the value and it is analyzed according to the destination field type. So if you change the filters on the source field, it has no effect on the search. You need to set the proper filters for the field you are searching in.

Comment: please add information from your comment in the answer as well. May be useful. Thanks for your time and help!!

Answer (score 1):

**This setup is working well for me**

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type = "index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type = "query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateAll="1" splitOnNumerics="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```